# Bucles usando ggplot en shiny

Tags: r, bucles, ggplot2, shiny

Me gustaría añadir en cada iteración del bucle con geom_point columnas de puntos. Sin embargo, se quedaba en el objeto `g` de `ggplot` con lo que hubiese en la última iteración. Tuve que usar una solución muy pobre con muchos ifs...

```
g <- ggplot(data = data) +
        xlab('Abscisas') + 
        ylab('Ordenadas') +
        ggtitle('Title') + 
        theme_minimal()+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=rel(1), face="bold"),
              axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=0.5, size = 10, face="bold"),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size= 10),
              axis.title.x.top=element_text(face="bold"))
      
        nsamples <- dim(data)[2]
        if(2 <= nsamples && names(data)[2] %in% input$sample_type){
          g <- g + geom_point(aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,2]), col=colors[2])
          g <- g + geom_line(aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,2]), col=colors[2])
        }
        if(3 <= nsamples && names(data)[3] %in% input$sample_type){
          g <- g + geom_point(aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,3]), col=colors[3])
          g <- g + geom_line(aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,3]), col=colors[3])
        }
```

Alguna idea? Gracias!!